# shell script to check availability of a file for 1 hour , after one hour if file not there , it will echo "Time Out"

Tags: shell-script, scripting

i wrote this code. but the problem is after every 300s it prints "Time over", when $fname present is got out from the loop. I want "time over" after 1hr if file not arrived, but after 300s it starts to print "time over"

```bsh
echo "enter file name"

read fname

START=`date +%s`
while [ $(( $(date +%s) - 3600 )) -lt $START ]; do
  if [ -e $fname ]
  then
    echo "$fname present"
    break
    sleep 300
  else
    echo "Time Over"
  fi
done
```

Comment: I am actually somewhat surprised that the 300s sleep is effective at all, because I would think the `break` statement would cause the script to never reach that part of the code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close already, but some aspects of your script look over-complicated.

You could try the following `while` loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

timeout=3600
granularity=300
elapsed=0

echo "Please enter the filename"
read -r file

while [ "$elapsed" -lt "$timeout" ]
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        break
    fi

    sleep "$granularity"
    elapsed=$((elapsed+granularity))
done

# Was the loop broken because the file appeared, or did it time out?
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file has appeared"
else
    echo "Time over"
fi
```

This will check every `$granularity` seconds if the file is present, until the `$timeout` value has been exceeded. If the file has appeared, the script will break out of the loop.

The problem with your approach was that the "Time over" output is in the `else` branch of your periodic check and hence will occur *every time the loop is iterated* if the file was not found. Instead, I would suggest checking *after the loop* if your test variable (in your script the output of `date`) has exceeded the boundary (indicates the loop timed out), or  alternatively (maybe even better) if the file is present, to decide whether or not to output the "Time over" message.

Comment: @ AdminBee  Your script will not break **immediately** after the file appeared, but up to `$granularity`seconds later.  Also, the way the loop is structured, it will miss a file appearing in the last sleep period, which should still be valid and not create a timeout. To avoid this, the sleep command needs to be positioned before the test.

Comment: @bey0nd This is true. I don't think it is possible to break _immediately_ upon file appearence with the rather basic approach shown in the OPs example, and I didn't try to achieve that as the OP doesn't seem to need it. This is also why I called the variable `$granularity`. Still, my comment implied it, and I will redact that. As for the second comment, you are right, I should correct that point; it can be handled by basing the check whether to output "Time over" on a test if the file exists _now_, rather than the value of `$elapsed`.

Comment: I think to archive a immediate break in such a script would be overkill. I just thought it should be mentioned was the script will achieve.

Comment: @bey0nd Correct, see my edited answer to your comment, and the edited answer to the OPs question. Good catch, by the way; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, which avoids the downsides of polling (the trade-off between resource consumption for short polling cycles and the delay in change detection for long polling cycles). The price to pay is that it relies on tools that may not be available to you, namely [inotify-tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools) and [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) (the latter from [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)).

Assuming that the meaning of "checking for the availability" is that you are waiting for a file (whose name is in the `fname` variable) to be created:

```sh
timeout 3600 sh -c '
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        printf "%s is present already\n" "$1"
        exit
    fi
    while inotifywait -qq -e create dir; do
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        printf "%s present\n" "$1"
        exit
    fi
done' mysh "$fname"
[ "$?" -eq 124 ] && echo "Time over"
```

`timeout` runs a command for the specified duration, which here is `3600` seconds (`s` is the default time unit). If the timeout is reached, `timeout` exits with a status of `124`; otherwise it exits with the status of the command it is running.

`inotifywait` waits for changes to the `dir` directory (the one which `$fname` is supposed to be created in); `create` is the event we are watching for; `-qq` makes it really quite.

This kind of check is sometimes implemented (e.g. in other Q/As on this site) as:

```sh
inotifywait -m ... --format "%f" | while read -r file; do ...
```

where `-m` (monitor mode) prevents `inotifywait` from exiting after the first matching event and the right hand side of the pipe receives the name of the file the event was about. Unfortunately this approach breaks if file names contain `<newline>`s.

This is why, in the code shown above, we don't use `-m` and we check for the existence of `$fname` twice. This approach is a bit fragile because `$fname` *might* be created between the first `[ -e "$1" ]` and the first run of `inotifywait` (and between executions of `inotifywait` too). It is also not really suitable in case lots of files were created in the watched directory, because every execution of `inotifywait` sets up its own watches.

Answer (score 0):

The following script reads `FILENAME` while checking for empty input, calculates `END_DATE` using the `date` command making sure wall-clock time of one hour is not exceeded, and checks if a file named `FILENAME` exists every `INTERVAL` seconds.
In case current date:

- **equals** `END_DATE`: one last file existence check takes place with the script exiting the while-loop right after (No waiting for 300 seconds).
- **exceeds** `END_DATE`: the while-loop breaks without checking for file existence.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "Enter file name to monitor: "

read FILENAME

if [ -z "${FILENAME}" ]
then
    echo -e "\nError: Filename is empty!\nExiting..."
    exit 1
fi

END_DATE=$(date --date='next hour' '+%s')
INTERVAL=300

FOUND="false"
while :
do
    CURRENT_DATE="$(date '+%s')"
    if [ "${CURRENT_DATE}" -gt "${END_DATE}" ]
    then
        break
    elif [ "${CURRENT_DATE}" -eq "${END_DATE}" ]
    then
        INTERVAL='0.1'   # Allow for one last check
    fi

    if [ -e "${FILENAME}" ]
    then
        FOUND="true"
        break
    fi
    sleep "${INTERVAL}"
done

if [ "${FOUND}" == "true" ]
then
    echo "${FILENAME} is present"
else
    echo "Time is Over"
fi
```